# Meaning of 'keep warm'

Tags: phrase-meaning

I got this expression from a job recruiter , Keep warm.
I am confused what it means, does it mean that I have hope of getting it? or indirectly telling me to move on?

The following is the actual reply:

> Hi James Bond,
>
> blah blah Please keep yourself warm. My apologies for the queen is still processing earlier MI6 candidates and they are moving very slow on the interviewing process due to internal projects.

Comment: Need more context, but in general it would mean "continued interest" ie a positive

Comment: Could it mean _continue to be prepared for interview_ a bit like a sports person continuing warm up exercises in case they are called on to perform at short notice or like keeping a car engine running for a quick getaway.

Comment: Seems like I wasnot sucessful for the job and it meant not a good sign, for any future reference

Answer (score -2):

It is a variant of "Stay Warm".

Hence it is a 'warm' (pun intended), end to an email, something that could as easily be replaced with "Stay Safe" or "Good Health".

It is essentially a less formal version of "Best Regards".

Please also refer https://www.italki.com/question/172747

Comment: I don't think so, because it seems a bit weird that you use it at the front of the email, don't you think so?

Comment: Heard that, so no, I do not think it is weird. It may not be very formal but is not unheard of.